# Loop not working as expected inside laravel job

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

I am using [league/csv](https://csv.thephpleague.com/) to parse a `csv` file and then later dumping those data to the database.

The structure looks like:

```
 $csv = Reader::createFromPath($csv_file_path, 'r');

 $csv->setOutputBOM(Reader::BOM_UTF8);
 $csv->addStreamFilter('convert.iconv.ISO-8859-15/UTF-8');

 $csv->setHeaderOffset(0); 
 $csv_header = $csv->getHeader();

 $loop = true;
 while($loop){

                $stmt = (new Statement())
                ->offset($offset)
                ->limit($limit)
                ;

                $records = $stmt->process($csv);

                foreach ($records as $record) 
                {
                    $rec_arr[] = array_values($record);
                }

                $records_arr = $service->trimArray($rec_arr);

                if(count($records_arr)>0)
                {
                    foreach($records_arr as $ck => $cv){
                         //map data and insert into database
                     }  

                }else{

                    $loop = false;
                }

        }
```

Currently, I am implementing this logic inside a laravel queue. It is successfully inserting the whole set of data but **it is not halting the process**.

It keeps getting stuck with message `processing`. However, if I removed that `while` loop then it will be stopped with message `processed`.

So, I think it should be something that I am implementing some bad logic there.

Looking for an idea to tackle with this.

Comment: Where is the count of `$records_arr` ever decremented? What does `$service->trimArray()` do?

Comment: It might be the code failed then queue status will not show that it's processed. Anything wrong that happen will be written in `storage/logs/laravel.log` as an error. Open that in text editor and read the last error on the file. Have you tried the same code in normal process before sending it to queue?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(count($records_arr)>0)
```

This line probably evaluates to `true` always.

Your code never reaches the `$loop = false;` end condition.

Answer (score 0):

@stuart thanks for your comment. It was because I had working loop previously which used to work with multiple ajax requests. However, now with queue too, I had placed records, rec_arr outside of loop. Here, I placed this array initialization inside while loop and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you explain further what you've changed to make it work?